# Validate the user credentials in Android APP with external database

Tags: php, android, mysql, validation

How to validate user credentials in an android app from an external database(xampp server). And the users are also of two types Admin as well a simple User. I want to redirect them to Different pages after validation

Comment: I have made a database. And a PHP script till now

Answer (score 0):

You can create API for this. For more info about API call see [Create a RESTful Services API in PHP](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html)

If you are having users of two types Admin as well a simple User, then you can return a parameter for user privilage from server and based on that you can redirect user to different page..